# <!DOCTYPE html> CSS issues

Tags: html, css, angularjs, doctype

Since adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`  I've been having css issues -

I know I know. I should have included `doctype` from the start - but I didn't. I believe the issue may be in the grids (plural - ag-grid) divs - possibly height related. Why I think this is because rest of page renders perfectly. When querying grid displays no data and seems to have a height of 0, with un-styled headers.

here is code for grid divs -

```
<div style="height: 100%; clear: left; width: 100%">

  <div style="min-width: 630px">

    <img ng-show="loaded == false" src="js/angular/assets/img/loading.gif" style="width: 536px; height: 224px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

    <img ng-show="error == true" src="js/angular/assets/img/error.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

  </div>
  <div ng-show="boxDataGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions1" class="ag-fresh" ng-style="expanded ? {width: '1550px'} : {}"></div>

  </div>

  <div ng-show="ladderGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions4" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

  </div>

  <div ng-show="ladderDataGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions5" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

is there anything that jumps our at anyone which needs to be changed?

Comment: Your inline styling, for starters.

Comment: so these should all be moved out to my css class?

Comment: Yes, inline styling should be avoided as it is renowned for causing specificity issues further down the line. It also increases the readability of your html.

Comment: Rightio will look into this thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

height cannot be in %, you have to give it manually like height: 400px;.

Answer (score 0):

we can't give 100% height without giving an element property to Position:absolute; or Position:fixed;. so if we are not using them we can't give height in %.

Now use in px or em or any other value.

```html
<div style="height: 500px; clear: left; width: 100%">

  <div style="min-width: 630px">

    <img ng-show="loaded == false" src="js/angular/assets/img/loading.gif" style="width: 536px; height: 224px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

    <img ng-show="error == true" src="js/angular/assets/img/error.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" />

  </div>
  <div ng-show="boxDataGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions1" class="ag-fresh" ng-style="expanded ? {width: '1550px'} : {}"></div>

  </div>

  <div ng-show="ladderGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions4" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

  </div>

  <div ng-show="ladderDataGrid == true && loaded == true" style="clear: both;">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions5" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```